# Redirect php page without javascript

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, header

Hello everyone is there any way to redirect page without header() and java script ?
is php has another function that can redirect page ?

first page ...

```
    <?php
    $item_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items ") or die(mysql_error());
    while($run_item=mysql_fetch_array($item_query))
    {
        $itemid=$run_item['item_id'];
        $name=$run_item['productname'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<a href='product.php?product=$userid'>$username</a>";
    }
?>
```

second page ...

```
if(isset($_GET['product'] ) && !empty($_GET['product'])){
    $itemid=$_GET['product'];
}else{
    $itemid= $_SESSION['item_id'];
}
$Item_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id=$itemid") or die( mysql_error());
while($run_item= mysql_fetch_array($mem_query)){
            $meid=$run_item['item_id'];
            $name=$run_item['name'];
}
    $my_id=$_SESSION['item_id'];
    echo '<h3> Your Name: '.$name."<br/>ID: ".$meid.'</h3>';
            $sendquery=mysql_query("SELECT fid FROM order WHERE inorder= $itemid AND userid= $my_id ")or die (mysql_error());
                    echo "<a href='actions.php?action=send&product=$itemid'> ordered </a>";
```

third page...
wher my second page come here when i click  on ordered  link

```
$action=$_GET['action'];
$itemid=$_GET['item'];
$my_id=$_SESSION['item_id'];
if($action=='send'){    
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO order VALUES ('','$my_id','$userid')");
}
    header('location:items.php?item=$itemid');
```

//header('location:items.php?item=$itemid');----> here i am  getting error

Unknown column '$item' in 'where clause'
i get this error when i click on ordered link.

Comment: why not use header()? it is perfect for the job

Comment: Why don't you want to use the right tools for the job?

Comment: Why PHP should have another tool to do the same as header??

Comment: beacuse header() is giving me error. it isnt working with $_Get variable

Comment: please share your header() code, maybe we can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: $productid=$_GET['product'];
$my_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
if($action=='send'){ 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO item VALUES ('','$my_id','$productid')");
}
 $url="profile.php?user=$productid";
 
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.onload = function () { top.location.href = '" . $url . "'; };</script>";//here i used  js but somone has  disabled his js from his browser and this  page wont  redirect.
 //header('location:profile.php?user=$productid');

Answer (score 4):

you can use meta refresh tag. no php, no javascript needed. syntax like so..

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=http://www.google.com/">
```

10 is seconds, URL is page to redirect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use header().

Example:

```
header("Location: /newpage.php");
```

Also you can use meta:

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.yoursite.com/">
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a meta tag that you can redirect, but you should use header(),

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=page.php">`